# handling dbnull data in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dbnull

I want to generate some formatted output of data retrieved from an MS-Access database and stored in a *DataTable* object/variable, myDataTable. However, some of the fields in myDataTable cotain *dbNull* data. So, the following VB.net code snippet will give errors if the value of any of the fields *lastname*, *intials*, or *sID* is *dbNull*.

```
   dim myDataTable as DataTable
   dim tmpStr as String
   dim sID as Integer = 1

   ...
   myDataTable = myTableAdapter.GetData() ' Reads the data from MS-Access table
   ...

   For Each myItem As DataRow In myDataTable.Rows

    tmpStr = nameItem("lastname") + " " + nameItem("initials")

    If myItem("sID")=sID Then
        ' Do something
    End If

    ' print tmpStr

   Next
```

So, how do i get the above code to work when the fields may contain *dbNull* without having to check each time if the data is dbNull as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105671/any-systemdbnullvalue-vs-any-is-systemdbnull)?

Comment: can you indicate WHERE (on which line) error occurs ? I suppose on `If MyItem("sID")=sID` but I'm not sure.

Comment: Are you sure that field name is "sID" ? It is special that a column name begin with "s"; normally prefixing a variable by "s" is to indicate that it is a String variable.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

The only way that i know of is to test for it, you can do a combined if though to make it easy.

```
If NOT IsDbNull(myItem("sID")) AndAlso myItem("sID") = sId Then
   'Do success
ELSE
   'Failure
End If
```

I wrote in VB as that is what it looks like you need, even though you mixed languages.

**Edit**

Cleaned up to use IsDbNull to make it more readable

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess it looks like mixed languanges because of the way I coded the comments with "//" instead of ticks for VB.net comments?

Comment: Yup!  And the == in the comparison

Comment: I think I fixed the code in the question to be pure VB.Net code. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: 10 years later. "+" as well. :P

Comment: The `DataRow` class has its own `IsNull` method.  That code would also not compile with `Option Strict On`.

Answer (score 37):

I got tired of dealing with this problem so I wrote a NotNull() function to help me out.

```
Public Shared Function NotNull(Of T)(ByVal Value As T, ByVal DefaultValue As T) As T
        If Value Is Nothing OrElse IsDBNull(Value) Then
                Return DefaultValue
        Else
                Return Value
        End If
End Function
```

Usage:

```
If NotNull(myItem("sID"), "") = sID Then
  ' Do something
End If
```

My NotNull() function has gone through a couple of overhauls over the years.  Prior to Generics, I simply specified everything as an Object.  But I much prefer the Generic version.

Comment: +1 Works very well, I've named it IsNull() as per SQL Server.

Comment: I prefer making the 2nd variable optional so that the signature is like this: `Public Shared Function NotNull(Of T)(ByVal Value As T, Optional ByVal DefaultValue As T = Nothing) As T` and it can be called as `If NotNull(myItem("sID")) = sID Then` or as listed above.

Comment: Doesn't work for me using VS 2008: tried to use this method with dataset generated dataTable and didn't work. `NotNull(rw.computer)` fails because the Dataset.Designer.vb code tries to convert to string before passing as argument. I suppose it would work with generic DataTable.

Comment: Put this into it when using nullable of integer:  Public Function NotNull(ByVal value As Integer?) As Integer
 Return NotNull(value, 0)
End Function

Comment: I love this method. Concise and effective. +1

Answer (score 12):

You can also use the Convert.ToString() and Convert.ToInteger() methods to convert items with DB null effectivly.

Answer (score 6):

A variation on [Steve Wortham's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1723822/7444103), to be used nominally with `nullable` types:

```
Private Shared Function GetNullable(Of T)(dataobj As Object) As T
    If Convert.IsDBNull(dataobj) Then
        Return Nothing
    Else
        Return CType(dataobj, T)
    End If
End Function
```

e.g.

```
mynullable = GetNullable(Of Integer?)(myobj)
```

You can then query `mynullable` (e.g., `mynullable.HasValue`)

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft came up with DBNull in .NET 1.0 to represent database NULL. However, it's a pain in the behind to use because you can't create a strongly-typed variable to store a genuine value or null. Microsoft sort of solved that problem in .NET 2.0 with nullable types. However, you are still stuck with large chunks of API that use DBNull, and they can't be changed.

Just a suggestion, but what I normally do is this:

1. All variables containing data read from or written to a database should be able to handle null values. For value types, this means making them Nullable(Of T). For reference types (String and Byte()), this means allowing the value to be Nothing.
2. Write a set of functions to convert back and forth between "object that may contain DBNull" and "nullable .NET variable". Wrap all calls to DBNull-style APIs in these functions, then pretend that DBNull doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the IsDbNull function:

```
  If  IsDbNull(myItem("sID")) = False AndAlso myItem("sID")==sID Then
    // Do something
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a BLL/DAL setup try the iif when reading into the object in the DAL

```
While reader.Read()
 colDropdownListNames.Add(New DDLItem( _
 CType(reader("rid"), Integer), _
 CType(reader("Item_Status"), String), _
 CType(reader("Text_Show"), String), _
 CType( IIf(IsDBNull(reader("Text_Use")), "", reader("Text_Use")) , String), _
 CType(reader("Text_SystemOnly"), String), _
 CType(reader("Parent_rid"), Integer)))
End While
```

Answer (score 1):

For the rows containing strings, I can convert them to strings as in changing

```
tmpStr = nameItem("lastname") + " " + nameItem("initials")
```

to

```
tmpStr = myItem("lastname").toString + " " + myItem("intials").toString
```

For the comparison in the *if* statement *myItem("sID")=sID*, it needs to be change to

```
myItem("sID").Equals(sID)
```

Then the code will run without any runtime errors due to *vbNull* data.

Answer (score 1):

```
   VB.Net
   ========
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Call conecDB()        'Connection to Database
    da.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("select max(RefNo) from BaseData", connDB)

    da.Fill(dt)

    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 And Convert.ToString(dt.Rows(0).Item(0)) = "" Then
        MsgBox("datbase is null")

    ElseIf dt.Rows.Count > 0 And Convert.ToString(dt.Rows(0).Item(0)) <> "" Then
        MsgBox("datbase have value")

    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be much easier to use:

> select ISNULL(sum(field),0) from tablename

Copied from: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/736515/How-do-I-avoide-Conversion-from-type-DBNull-to-typ

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Friends**

**This is the shortest method to check db Null in DataGrid and convert to string**

1. create the cell validating event and write this code
2. If Convert.ToString(dgv.CurrentCell.Value) = "" Then
3. CurrentCell.Value = ""
4. End If

Answer (score 0):

This is **BY FAR** the easiest way to convert `DBNull` to a string.
The trick is that you **CANNOT** use the `TRIM` function (which was my initial problem) when referring to the fields from the database:

**BEFORE** (produced error msg):

```
Me.txtProvNum.Text = IIf(Convert.IsDBNull(TRIM(myReader("Prov_Num"))), "", TRIM(myReader("Prov_Num")))
```

**AFTER** (no more error msg :-) ):

```
Me.txtProvNum.Text = IIf(Convert.IsDBNull(myReader("Prov_Num")), "", myReader("Prov_Num"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, but not obvious.

```
DbNull.Value.Equals(myValue)
```

I hate VB.NET

Answer (score 0):

For your problem, you can use following special workaround coding that only exists in `VB.Net`.

```
Dim nId As Integer = dr("id") + "0"
```

This code will replace `DBNull` value contained in `id` column by integer 0.

The only acceptable default value is "0" because this expression must also be used when `dr("id")` is not NULL !

So, using this technic, your code would be

```
   Dim myDataTable as DataTable
   Dim s as String
   Dim sID as Integer = 1

   ...
   myDataTable = myTableAdapter.GetData() ' Reads the data from MS-Access table
   ...

   For Each myItem As DataRow In myDataTable.Rows
       s = nameItem("lastname") + " " + nameItem("initials")
       If myItem("sID") + "0" = sID Then
           ' Do something
       End If
   Next
```

I have tested this solution and it works on my PC on Visual Studio 2022.

PS: if `sID` can be equal to 0 and you want to do something distinct when `dr("sID")` value is NULL, you must also adept you program and perhaps use `Extension` as proposed at end of this answer.

I have tested following statements

```
Dim iNo1 As Integer = dr("numero") + "0"
Dim iNo2 As Integer = dr("numero") & "0" '-> iNo = 10 when dr() = 1
Dim iNo3 As Integer = dr("numero") + "4" '-> iNo = 5  when dr() = 1
Dim iNo4 As Integer = dr("numero") & "4" '-> iNo = 14 when dr() = 1
Dim iNo5 As Integer = dr("numero") + "" -> System.InvalidCastException : 'La conversion de la chaîne "" en type 'Integer' n'est pas valide.'
Dim iNo6 As Integer = dr("numero") & "" -> System.InvalidCastException : 'La conversion de la chaîne "" en type 'Integer' n'est pas valide.'
Dim iNo7 As Integer = "" + dr("numero") -> System.InvalidCastException : 'La conversion de la chaîne "" en type 'Integer' n'est pas valide.'
Dim iNo8 As Integer = "" & dr("numero") -> System.InvalidCastException : 'La conversion de la chaîne "" en type 'Integer' n'est pas valide.'
Dim iNo9 As Integer = "0" + dr("numero")
Dim iNo0 As Integer = "0" & dr("numero")
```

Following statements works also correctly

```
Dim iNo9 As Integer = "0" + dr("numero")
Dim iNo0 As Integer = "0" & dr("numero")
```

I recognize that is a little tricky.

If trick are not your tips, you can also define an `Extension` so that following code works.

```
Dim iNo = dr.GetInteger("numero",0)
```

where GetInteger() code can be following

```
Module Extension
    '***********************************************************************
    '* GetString()
    '***********************************************************************

    <Extension()>
    Public Function GetString(ByRef rd As SqlDataReader, ByRef sName As String, Optional ByVal sDefault As String = "") As String
        Return GetString(rd, rd.GetOrdinal(sName), sDefault)
    End Function

    <Extension()>
    Public Function GetString(ByRef rd As SqlDataReader, ByVal iCol As Integer, Optional ByVal sDefault As String = "") As String
        If rd.IsDBNull(iCol) Then
            Return sDefault
        Else
            Return rd.Item(iCol).ToString()
        End If
    End Function

    '***********************************************************************
    '* GetInteger()
    '***********************************************************************

    <Extension()>
    Public Function GetInteger(ByRef rd As SqlDataReader, ByRef sName As String, Optional ByVal iDefault As Integer = -1) As Integer
        Return GetInteger(rd, rd.GetOrdinal(sName), iDefault)
    End Function

    <Extension()>
    Public Function GetInteger(ByRef rd As SqlDataReader, ByVal iCol As Integer, Optional ByVal iDefault As Integer = -1) As Integer
        If rd.IsDBNull(iCol) Then
            Return iDefault
        Else
            Return rd.Item(iCol)
        End If
    End Function

End Module
```

These methods are more explicitely and less tricky.

In addition, it is possible to define default values other than ZERO and also specific version as `GetBoolean()` or `GetDate()`, etc ...

Another possibility is to report SQL default conversion in SQL command using `COALESCE` SQL command !