# Checking for DBNull throws a StrongTypingException

Tags: .net, vb.net, dbnull

I am using a dataset to pull data from a DB. One of the fields in a row is `NULL`. I know this. However, the following vb.net code throws a `StrongTypingException` (in the autogenerated get_SomeField() method in the dataset designer):

```
If Not IsDBNull(aRow.SomeField) Then
'do something
End If
```

According to documentation and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222834/handling-dbnull-data-in-vb-net) it should be fine.

edit: `If aRow.SomeField is DBNull.Value Then` also returns the same error. Argh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that in the related question it is talking about an untyped value (i.e. `object`) via an indexer. When you go via `.SomeField`, the type is already included - so this could be `int` etc. And it wouldn't make sense to try `IsDBNull` on an `int`, as an `int` can **never** be `DBNull`.

Essentially the `SomeField` is a wrapper for (excuse the C# accent...)

```
public int SomeField {
    get { return (int) this["someFieldName"]; }
    set { this["someFieldName"] = value; }
}
```

I'm not a huge `DataTable` person, but you could try checking it by name/index/column; or marking the column as nullable so that it is `Nullable<int>` (in the example above).

Comment: Thanks, mate. The line was trying to cast a null to column that had the default null behaviour as "throw exception". Datasets cause me pain.

Answer (score 22):

Just some additional information: The exception comes because you are using a **strongly typed DataSet**. [StrongTypingException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.strongtypingexception.aspx) documentation says it:

> The exception that is thrown by a strongly typed DataSet when the user accesses a DBNull value.

The usage of strongly typed DataSets is slightly different from that of the untyped ones. With strongly typed DataSets you get automatically some extended/additional methods for your fields that you can call. In your case you would very likely have to call:

```
If Not aRow.IsSomeFieldNull Then
   'do something
End If
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this:
 aRow.IsSomeFieldNull

Answer (score 4):

There is a neat way of going around it. But you need to be aware of consequences.

To prevent exception of occuring you can change in DataSet field property NullValue to either "Null" or "Empty" (whatever suits your needs). Default is set to "Throw Exception".

For a reference look here: [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya91ataz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
**DateTime? ToDate = (row.IsToDateNull()) ? null : row.IsToDate;**
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is old but what i'm adding doesn't seem to be in any of the other answers.

If you use

```
If Not IsDBNull(aRow.item("SomeField")) Then
    'do something
End If
```

This will not throw an exception even if you're using a strongly typed dataset

Comment: This - simplest.