# How to compare a DBnull expression

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have the following code:

```
dsParticippantInfo.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Contract_Amt")
```

Which has value of DBnull.

now I want to compare it:

```
if dsParticippantInfo.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Contract_Amt")=nothing
```

....

...

I get

```
Run-time exception thrown : System.InvalidCastException - Operator is not valid for type 'DBNull' and 'Nothing'.
```

Ideas how to compare this value to see if it contains a `DBnull`?

`if dsParticippantInfo.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Contract_Amt")=system.DBnull` also returns an error.

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222834/handling-dbnull-data-in-vb-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`IsDBNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tckcces5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function:

> Returns a `Boolean` value that indicates whether an expression evaluates to the `System.DBNull` class.

```
If IsDBNull(dsParticippantInfo.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Contract_Amt")) Then
    ' value is null
End If
```

Comment: Checking ... As this reply came first.,

Comment: @SNash Actually, it was not the first one.

Comment: I saw your reply came 30 seconds before Dennis Traub

Answer (score 4):

You can either use the `IsDBNull()` function

```
If IsDbNull(dsParticippantInfo.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Contract_Amt")) Then ...
```

or compare agains `DBNull.Value`

```
If dsParticippantInfo.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Contract_Amt") Is DBNull.Value Then ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use [Convert.DBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.dbnull.aspx) (same as `DBNull.Value`):

```
If dsParticippantInfo.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Contract_Amt") Is Convert.DBNull Then
  ' value is null
End If
```

I prefer this syntax, because it's very similar to `Is Nothing` comparison.

Answer (score 1):

DBNull.Value provides a way to do comparisons. So you can write:

```
if dsParticippantInfo.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Contract_Amt")=DBNull.Value
```

Comment: Well, C# is my "native language" so I'm not 100%, but using this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1 , I thought that `DBNull.Value.Equals(a)` was the equivalent of `a=DBNull.Value` (That would be `DBNull.Value==a` in C#) Was I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
`If IsDbNull() Then
 End If
`
```