# Why Does NULL value in database fails Not Is nothing in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am not vb.net expert, but made to work on it for now.
Retrieving value for database, which in some cases Is NULL for a datetime column (Sql database).
When it is retrieved in vb.net using something like this.

```
 select testcolumn from testtable
```

and result converted to datatable.
the value fails validation(even though the retrieved value in database is null)

```
If Not dt("testcolumn") Is Nothing

End If
```

Ideally this validation is point for me which decides whether the value should be assigned to a property for class. but as this fails.next exception I get is Invalid cast, as i try to do something Like

```
myClass.datetimeProperty=dt("testcolumn").ToString()
```

Any reason for this, and is only way to perform additional validation of

```
If Not string.isnullOrEmpty(dt("testcolumn)
```

Comment: Check on DBNull.Value

Comment: possible duplicate of [handling dbnull data in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222834/handling-dbnull-data-in-vb-net)

Comment: (It's admittedly not an exact duplicate, but that looks like a good canonical question to me, and is broad enough to also cover your question.)

Comment: If `dt` is actually a [`DataRow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow(v=vs.110).aspx) class, then that contains a separate `IsNull` method to check for nullability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking on `Nothing`, you have to check on `DBNull.Value`.

```
If dt("testcolumn") IsNot DbNull.Value
'your code
End If
```

Or another alternative:

```
If NOT IsDbNull(dt("testcolumn")) Then
   'your code
End If
```