# I can't Refer to some Cell as Null in DataTable

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem with following code in `vb.net`

```
For Each Row As DataRow In DataTable
   If Row("FieldName") = vbNull Then
      MsgBox(...)
   End If
Next Row
```

A message error appears telling me that "=" can't be used with vbNull, I searched for a solution without any  luck, any help? I just need to make something if some cell in some Row in Datatable is `Null`

Comment: You didn't search very hard, google gave me the results in seconds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [handling dbnull data in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222834/handling-dbnull-data-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 0):

VBA has a function [IsNull()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278616.aspx)

So is should work if you use this:

```
If IsNull(Row("FieldName")) Then
```