# Avoid DBNull in VB.NET?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, devexpress

I want to change the color of the cell in GridView based on the condition. If age is less than 70 then the cell back color will be `Color.Pink` otherwise `Color.Lime`. I have a table in **SQL Server** and it has column `Age` in it with data type `nvarchar(20)`. Here's my code:

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowCellStyle(sender As Object, e As RowCellStyleEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCellStyle
        Try
            If e.Column.FieldName = "Age" Then

                If e.CellValue < 70 Then
                    e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Pink
                ElseIf e.CellValue = "" Then
                    e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.White
                Else
                    e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Lime
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try   
    End Sub
```

It's working however it gives me the error `operator '<' is not defined for type 'dbnull' and type 'integer'` every time it reads a row with no value in column `Age`. So I added `ElseIf e.CellValue = "" Then` to check if there's a row with no value but it still gives me the same error. I can bypass the error by using `Try Catch`  but I want to resolve this issue as it may bring problems in the future.

Screenshot:

[image: error message]

Comment: Take a look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222834/handling-dbnull-data-in-vb-net) that has a similiar problem, something along the lines of ```If NOT IsDbNull(e.CellValue) Then ...```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely ignore the empty (Nothing and DBNull.Value) values something like this:

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowCellStyle(sender As Object, e As RowCellStyleEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCellStyle
    If e.CellValue Is Nothing OrElse e.CellValue Is DBNull.Value Then Return
    'Try
    If e.Column.FieldName = "Age" Then
        If e.CellValue < 70 Then
            e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Pink
        ElseIf e.CellValue = "" Then
            e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.White
        Else
            e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Lime
        End If
    'End If
    'Catch ex As Exception
    '    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    'End Try
    End If
End Sub
```