# best way to prevent Null failure with string casting

Tags: c#, sql, string, parsing, null

```
_callReportCode = reader["Call Report Code"].ToString();
```

I am attempting to handle the possibility for the object I am calling ToString on to be NULL.
I am going to be using the above statement with several variables and I dont want to make an individual try/catch for each one... what is the best way to do null checking for strings.

Other datatypes ive been doing this:

```
int.TryParse(reader["Account Number"].ToString(), out _accountNumber);
```

In this code "reader" refers to a SqlDataReader but thats not really important for this question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10104842/195488

Comment: Try/Catch would _not_ be the appropriate mechanism to use if you wanted to test individually - you should check if `reader['blah']` is `Null` before calling `.ToString()`. Exceptions should _never_ be part of your normal execution flow, they're expensive and not designed to be used in that way (eg too easy to catch the wrong thing if you don't think carefully)

Comment: Unrelated, but I'm curious as to what Account Number should be an integer.

Comment: Even though I agree with the most voted answer, I believe you should write an extension method in order to reuse your code anywhere. I don't really like using repeating code over again.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx): `??`

```
callReportCode = (reader["Call Report Code"] ?? "").ToString();
```

If the data in your field is `DBNull.Value` (rather than `null`), this will still work, because `DBNull.Value` is not `null`, so the `??` won't be used, and `DBNull.Value.ToString()` is `""`, which is what you'd want.

Comment: It will throw NPE if the object is null

Comment: @0A0D - It'll only throw an exception if `reader` is null.  This will work correctly if `reader["Call Report Code"]` is null.

Comment: If the data is `DBNull`, you cannot use the null coalescing operator.

Comment: @Matthew - Sure you can.  `DBNull.Value.ToString()` returns `""`.

Comment: `(DBNull.Value ?? "").ToString()` doesn't even compile

Comment: if the reader returns null for that column name, it means the column itself doesn't exist, if it returns DBNull, it means the database returned a null value.  They are two distinct things, one is an application problem (you're requesting a column that doesn't exist), and the other isn't (column values can be null [DBNull]).

Comment: @AndreCalil - That doesn't compile, but `reader["Call Report Code"]` is of type `object`, so the actual scenario will.

Comment: @Bobson Yes, but `DBNull` inherits from `Object` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx). I can see that you've never used it in a real project. It will return `DBNull` from the DB if the column is null, it's a very usual problem.

Comment: You cannot convert `object` to `string` using the null coalescing, you could cast it to string, however if the underlying data is neither `null` (not `DBNull`) nor `string`, you will get a cast exception.  If you try and cast `DBNull` to string, you will get a cast exception.

Comment: @Matthew - `object foo = DateTime.Now; (foo ?? "").ToString();` works.  `object foo = 2.3; (foo ?? "").ToString();` works.  `object foo = null; (foo ?? "").ToString();` works.  `object foo = DBnull.Value; (foo ?? "").ToString();` works.  Give me an example where you get an exception with this pattern.

Comment: Sorry, I was using an erroneous example of `string x = y ?? "";`, I was missing the `ToString` portion.

Comment: @Matthew - It's ok, I've been there.  I'm sorry I got so defensive about it.  I use this pattern a lot, so I was pretty confident in it.

Comment: No need to apologize, I was the one who made this mistake.

Answer (score 11):

```
Convert.ToString(reader["Call Report Code"]);
```

It will return `string.Empty` if the value is null.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/astxcyeh.aspx

Update: it also works with `DBNull`, I've just verified.

**Update 2**: I decided to bring a more complete test here, just to be sure:

```
DBNull dbNull = null;
DBNull dbNullEmpty = DBNull.Value;
string stringNull = null;
string stringEmpty = string.Empty;

var outcome1 = Convert.ToString(dbNull);//Empty string
var outcome2 = Convert.ToString(dbNullEmpty);//Empty string
var outcome3 = Convert.ToString(stringNull);//NULL
var outcome4 = Convert.ToString(stringEmpty);//Empty string
```

Comment: It still throws an exception when I try this... _callReportCode = Convert.ToString(reader["Call Report Code"]); the whole point is to get it in that variable

Comment: @John Can you share details of the exception?

Comment: it does not seems to be working the way msdn says, can be checked by Convert.ToString(null).EndsWith(""); vs string.empty.EndsWith(""); The stmt Convert.ToString(null).EndsWith("") will throw object ref exception.

Comment: @AnilKumar yeah, but that's kinda expected. `Convert.ToString(null)` returns null, then you try to call the method `.EndsWith("")` from it.

Comment: It will not return string.Empty if the value is null, it will return null.

Comment: @AnilKumar I've updated the answer to bring all the situations, please check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If your string is nullable, you need to check the value returned from the `SqlDataReader` against `DBNull.Value`:

```
_callReportCode = reader["Call Report Code"] as string;
```

If the object returned by `reader["Call Report Code"]` is *not* a `string`, it's `DBNull.Value`, so the `as` cast is going to set the value of `_callReportCode` to `null` as well.

If you must set the string to a non-null in case the database value is missing, add `??`, like this:

```
_callReportCode = (reader["Call Report Code"] as string) ?? string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to never convert `ToString` when the data isn't a string, and if the data is already a string, then calling `ToString` is redundant, and a cast is all that's required.

I am making an assumption that the datatype in the database is integer, in which case, you can use a nullable int.

```
int? accountNumber = reader["Account Number"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (int?)reader["Account Number"];
```

I have made an extension method to do just this thing.

```
public static class SqlDataReaderExtensions
{
    public static T Field<T>(this SqlDataReader reader, string columnName)
    {
        object obj = reader[columnName];

        if (obj == null)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(
                string.Format(
                    "reader does not contain column: {0}",
                    columnName
                )
            );
        }

        if (obj is DBNull)
        {
            obj = null;
        }

        return (T)obj;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
int? accountType = reader.Field<int?>("Account Number"); // will return NULL or the account number.
```

Comment: What do you do with the value later? like if I am going to pass it into a constructor? do I have to change that constructor to take a nullable int?

Comment: That depends on your application, what does it mean to your application when `Account Number` is null?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I have found is

```
_callReportCode = reader["Call Report Code"] + "";
```

Comment: Please explain your answer in very brief.

Answer (score 1):

i have some easiest and common Method.

```
 public static string ToNULLString(this string Values)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Values))
            {
                return "";
            }
            else
            {
                return Values.ToString();
            }
        }
```

use in C#

```
string item = null;
string value = item.ToNULLString();
```

Answer (score 0):

_callReportCode = Convert.ToString(reader["Call Report Code"]) should ensure there are no null there.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a method that you call when you want to make the check.
This way you have to type the try catch only once...
or you can create an extension method for string class to do this

Answer (score 0):

Use following line of code:

```
_callReportCode = String.IsNullorEmpty(reader["Call Report Code"]) ?
                  String.Empty :
                  reader["Call Report Code"].ToString();
```

instead of the following line:

```
_callReportCode = reader["Call Report Code"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I like using a combination of the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) and the [null conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595(v=vs.140).aspx):

```
string nn = MyObject.myNullableVar?.ToString() ?? "";
```

it's basically the same as this

```
string ss = (MyObject.MyNullableVar == null) ? "" : MyObject.MyNullableVar.ToString();
```

but shorter.

Answer (score -1):

You can perform a check using `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` to ensure that it isn't going to be null, or you could write an extension method to perform some action if it's not null and another / nothing if it is.