# Curly Braces In C#

Tags: c#, syntax

I was playing around with some code and I was wondering if any can tell me what the curly braces in this code represents. I thought it would've been for an empty object but that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
 Person person = new Person{};

            if (person is {}){
                Console.WriteLine("Person is empty.");
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("Person is not empty.");
            }
```

It compiles just fine; but if I populate the properties of the person class it still falls into the person is empty part of the if statement.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59715428

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171710/creating-object-parameters-in

Comment: You have three different uses of curly braces in play here (block, object initializer, pattern matching), and links to explanations of two of them. For a usable answer, please indicate which one you're asking about.

Comment: I guess you answered my question. I'm referring to the if statement where person is {} ; so I'm assuming this if for pattern matching.

Comment: It's an anonymous object that behaves like an empty `IEnumerable<object>`.  Try this: `var foo = new {};`

Comment: @Crow: Wrong curlies :-) - It () means 'not null'

Comment: @Crowcoder OP is talking about line 3 char 14 and 15

Comment: @Crow is right. it means 'not null' just tested the logic.

Comment: That is a whole lot easier to read than Person != null

Comment: You are using [property patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#property-patterns) but with no requirement for a specific property value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

{} means in this context a pattern matching of any type to check if the instance is not null:

```
if(person != null){     //the same as: if(person is {})...

}
```

It is like a var keyword for pattern matching, so you do not need to specify/repeat the type explicitly (although you know it).

```
if(GetPersonFromDb() is {} person){     //the same as: var person = GetPersonFromDb(); if(person != null)...

}
```

More info (see the section *Special match expressions*): https://hackernoon.com/whats-pattern-matching-in-c-80-6l7h3ygm

Comment: Thanks. Still think `GetPersonFromDb() is var person` would have been much clearer to majority of C# devs, and we wouldn't be searching for "what it means". :) I miss the old C# team who were very very hard to sell on introducing "new" stuff like this.