# chek if value of data is null c#

Tags: c#, null

I'm trying to get record and store data into variable

```
Image Image = _context.Images.FirstOrDefault(u => u.imgID== Images.imgID);
var ImageName = Image.Name;
```

I'm getting this error. probably something is null in record.

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
    
    <Image>5__11 was null.
```

I'm trying to do null check but probably I do something wrong

```
if (Image == null || Image.ImageName == null) Image.ImageName = "";
```

But I'm getting same error. How can I fix this ?

Comment: You should be doing that null check before you do `var ImageName = Image.Name;` You could include the null checks as part of the assignment like this: `var ImageName = Image?.Name ?? "";`

Comment: You can't set the `ImageName` property on the `Image` object if the `Image` object is null. Try `var ImageName = Image?.Name ?? string.Empty;` That will set `ImageName` to be the empty string if `Image` or `Image.Name` is null.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if an object is null in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417902/checking-if-an-object-is-null-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do simple null check as follow:

```
Image Image = _context.Images.FirstOrDefault(u => u.imgID== Images.imgID);

// If Image is not null, then use Image.Name, else when it is null, then assing empty string.
var ImageName = Image != null ? Image.Name : String.Empty;
```

Also depends on your function that this is in, but you can utilize something called Null guards.

Comment: Or `var ImageName = Image?.Name ?? string.Empty;`, though that would also assign `string.Empty` if `Name` was null.

Comment: @RufusL Agreed. It is basically the same, but since he is begginer my version should be more easy to read for him.

Answer (score 1):

David,

When you use `FirstOrDefault` it means that if it can't find any item in your `_context.Images` collection that matches your criteria, it will return null.  So therefore in your first line, imagine it results in this:

```
Image Image = null;
```

This means that the 2nd line will return you a `NullReferenceException` because you are essentially doing this in the code:

```
var ImageName = null.Name; // YOU CAN'T ACCESS the Name property because the Image was null!
```

Does this make sense?  To avoid the NullReferenceException, you should always check for null before trying to access its properties.  Like this:

```
Image Image = _context.Images.FirstOrDefault(u => u.imgID== Images.imgID);

if (Image != null)
{
    var ImageName = Image.Name;
}
```