# How to select multiple elements into array in Linq query?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

Net core application. I have below query in my application

```
 var result  = sourceProposal.Quotes
      .Where(x=>x.QuotationId == sourceQuoteId)
      .FirstOrDefault()
      .QuoteLines.Select(x=>(x.Quantity,x.WtgType)).ToArray();
```

This yields in two array elements such as

```
0 element   1, "string1"
1 element   2, "string2"
```

What I am expecting is

```
(int[] sourceQuantity, string[] destinationTurbineType) = sourceProposal.Quotes
           .Where(x=>x.QuotationId == sourceQuoteId)
           .FirstOrDefault()
           .QuoteLines.Select(x=>(x.Quantity,x.WtgType)).ToArray();
```

I want to copy to tuple which has  `int[] sourceQuantity`, `string[] destinationTurbineType` this piece of code is not working and throwing error does not contain definition for destructor and no accessible extension method Descontruct accepting first argument of type `int(sourceQuantity, string destinationTurbineType)[]`.

Can someone help me to copy values to `sourceQuantity` and `destinationTurbineType`. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: _"What I am expecting is"_ - why are you expecting this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Select<TSource,TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-select-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-1)))) returns enumerable/queryable of the type returned by selector (`IEnumerabe<TResult>`/`IQueryable <TResult>`).

If you want to achieve this with LINQ you can use `Aggregate`:

```cs
// note that sourceQuantity and destinationTurbineType would be lists, not arrays
var (sourceQuantity, destinationTurbineType) = sourceProposal.Quotes
    .Where(x=>x.QuotationId == sourceQuoteId)
    .FirstOrDefault()
    .QuoteLines
    .Aggregate((ints: new List<int>(), strs: new List<string>()), (aggr, curr) =>
    {
        aggr.ints.Add(curr.Quantity);
        aggr.strs.Add(curr.WtgType);
        return aggr;
    });
```

Or just use simple `for` loop and copy data to destination arrays (possibly move to some extension method). Something along this lines:

```cs
var quoteLines = sourceProposal.Quotes
    .Where(x=>x.QuotationId == sourceQuoteId)
    .FirstOrDefault()
    .QuoteLines; // assuming it is materialized collection with indexer like an array or list
int[] sourceQuantity = new int[quoteLines.Length]; // or Count
string[] destinationTurbineType = new string[quoteLines.Count()];
for(int i = 0; i < quoteLines.Length; i++)
{
   var curr = quoteLines[i];
   sourceQuantity[i] = curr.Quantity;
   destinationTurbineType[i] = curr.WtgType;
}
```

Comment: Could you shorten this by removing the Where and doing the match on QuotationId in the FirstOrDefault?

Comment: @sr28 yes. The original code has also a problem with `Default` part.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer, It is working, May I know if there is any issue with original code

Comment: @MrPerfect was glad to help! `FirstOrDefault` will return `null` if the type is reference type and nothing was matched, so `.FirstOrDefault().QuoteLines` will throw NRE.

Comment: Yes got it how we can avid it sir?

Comment: @MrPerfect using null checks ([several options here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6417902/2501279)) and conditional logic. Or using null [conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)(note that with value types it can behave in not very obvious way).

Comment: `resultSelector: acc => (acc.ints.ToArray(), acc.strs.ToArray()` will convert the lists to arrays

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no built-in LINQ method to do this. But you could write your own extension method. Something like the following:

```cs
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static (TFirst[] xs, TSecond[] ys) Unzip<TFirst, TSecond>(this IEnumerable<(TFirst, TSecond)> zipped)
    {
        var xs = new List<TFirst>();
        var ys = new List<TSecond>();
        foreach (var (x, y) in zipped)
        {
            xs.Add(x);
            ys.Add(y);
        }
        return (xs.ToArray(), ys.ToArray());
    }
}

var (xs, ys) =
    new[] { 1, 2, 3 }
    .Zip(new[] { "a", "b", "c" })
    .Unzip();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", xs)); // 1, 2, 3
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", ys)); // a, b, c
```

Or in the case of your example, you could then use:

```cs
(int[] sourceQuantity, string[] destinationTurbineType) = sourceProposal.Quotes
           .Where(x=>x.QuotationId == sourceQuoteId)
           .FirstOrDefault()
           .QuoteLines.Select(x=>(x.Quantity,x.WtgType)).Unzip();
```