# Why is my Rigidbody != null immediately after seeing that it is null?

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine, null

I am checking to see if "My Game Object" has a Rigidbody.  It does not.  But the conditional for the null check on Rigidbody fails, despite having just been proven null.

Why is this happening?  How can I make my condition block run?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NullChecker : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Start()
    {
        GameObject go = GameObject.Find("My Game Object");
        CheckIfNull<Rigidbody>(go);
    }

    public void CheckIfNull<ComponentType>(GameObject gameObject)
    {
        ComponentType component = gameObject.GetComponent<ComponentType>();
        Debug.Log("Component is " + component); //"Component is null"
        if (component == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Inside null check"); //Never prints
        }
        Debug.Log("Finished null check"); //Does print
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From other research ([Equals(item, null) or item == null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507383/equalsitem-null-or-item-null) and [Unity Forums](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/981521/why-is-my-null-immediately-after-seeing-that-is-nu.html)) and to elaborate on usr's answer:

I needed to guarantee that a Component was being passed through in my CheckIfNull header.  The updated code looks like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NullChecker : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Start()
    {
        GameObject go = GameObject.Find("My Game Object");
        CheckIfNull<Rigidbody>(go);
    }

    public void CheckIfNull<ComponentType>(GameObject gameObject) where ComponentType : Component
    {
        ComponentType component = gameObject.GetComponent<ComponentType>();
        Debug.Log("Component is " + component); //"Component is null"
        if (component == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Inside null check"); //Never prints
        }
        Debug.Log("Finished null check"); //Does print
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`null` object references to not format as `"null"`. They format as an empty string. `component` was not null. It's `ToString` output was `"null"`.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure gameObject.GetComponent() doesn't return null. It has to return an object that has a .ToString() method that returns "null".
If it actually was null the result of

```
"Component is " + component
```

would be "Component is" because null will be an empty string in string concatenation.

Can you debug the code and set a breakpoint to see what GetComponent returns? Check it in your Immediate window or your Locals window.